# Proving that there exist no linear transformations such that...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone give me a hint for how to prove that there exists no one-to-one linear transformation between the finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ if dim $W \lt$ dim $V$?

I thought that it had to with free parameters, but I can't seem to crack it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the rank of a linear transformation $V\to W$ by definition cannot exceed $\dim W$, the rank-nullity theorem says that the nullity of such a linear transformation is at least $\dim V-\dim W>0$. But an injective (one-to-one) linear transformation must have nullity equal to$~0$, so this is not possible.